# Android Studio crashes on Mac OS El Capitan randomly, when ADB is initialized

Tags: macos, android-studio, intellij-idea, adb

I am using newest version of Android Studio (2.0.0-beta5) and I am observing very strange behavior. If I turn on ADB from within Android Studio (no matter for what purpose - seeing logs, debugging or installing app) Android Studio crashes repeateadely.

So far I found only one solution to that problem, which is quite unsatisfying: making it impossible for AS to localize adb (I achieve that by moving adb from platform-tools to any other localization.

I have already tried:
1. Updating java (I have version 1.8.0_74-b02) but happened on earlier versions as well (for at least u71)
2. Downgrading Android Studio (to latest stable version - 1.5.0)
3. Running different devices connected to adb. Haven't tried with no device connected so far.

Here is what log happens everytime before crash (from ~/Library/Logs/AndroidStudioXX.X/

```
2016-02-18 16:02:07,374 [1025648]   INFO -                 #com.android.ddmlib - Opening a debugger listener at port 8602 for client with pid 1789 
2016-02-18 16:02:07,374 [1025648]   WARN -            #com.android.ddmlib - Broken pipe
java.io.IOException: Broken pipe
at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcher.write0(Native Method)
at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write(SocketDispatcher.java:29)
at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:69)
at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:40)
at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:336)
at com.android.ddmlib.JdwpPacket.write(JdwpPacket.java:179)
at com.android.ddmlib.Client.send(Client.java:654)
at com.android.ddmlib.jdwp.JdwpAgent.send(JdwpAgent.java:92)
at com.android.ddmlib.HandleHeap.sendREAQ(HandleHeap.java:349)
at com.android.ddmlib.Client.requestAllocationStatus(Client.java:517)
at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor.createClient(DeviceMonitor.java:573)
at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor.openClient(DeviceMonitor.java:545)
at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor.processIncomingJdwpData(DeviceMonitor.java:507)
at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor.deviceClientMonitorLoop(DeviceMonitor.java:403)
at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor.access$100(DeviceMonitor.java:65)
at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor$1.run(DeviceMonitor.java:326)
```

Here is where I figured out it might be connected with adb, so decided to disable it.

Will appreciate any help, since it makes my work really difficult.

EDIT:

After clean installation of latest stable version (1.5.1) error still occurs. The difference is, that I cannot see any logs, seems like there is a black hole in them, starting few minutes before crash. Pasting MacOs problem report which displays directly after crash.

```
System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes:       KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000020
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

VM Regions Near 0x20:
--> 
    __TEXT                 0000000100000000-000000010000b000 [   44K]     r-x/rwx SM=COW  /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/MacOS/studio

Application Specific Information:
Java information:
Exception type: Bus Error (0xa) at pc=7fffa174f103

 Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (20.65-b04-468 mixed mode      macosx-amd64)

Current thread (1070d5800):  JavaThread "AWT-AppKit" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=2116415488, stack(7fff5f400000,7fff5fc00000)]
Stack: [7fff5f400000,7fff5fc00000]
```

I also tried limiting myself to one instance of AS and disabling all other apps that might use adb (like Vysor). No result...

Comment: You could file a bug report with Google, since you *are* using their ***beta*** version...

Comment: @CaptJak he said that downgrading AS to stable (1.5.0) versions didn't help so it's not related to beta.

Comment: Nonetheless, @Than, it seems that installing the beta may have broken something, since he most likely was not experiencing problems before upgrading. And he did say upgrade and downgrade, which leads us to believe that he didn't do a side-by-side installation.

Comment: Anyways... 1.5.0 is not the latest stable version. Try forcing an update on the 1.5.0 version to see if you can update to 1.5.1. Perhaps that will patch it up.

Comment: I clean installed AS 1.5.1, no results... Posted some more info in original post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like i finally found the root cause of the issue... It has nothing to do with adb, nor java version nor AS version. It comes as a result of developing on multiple screens. There already is a discussion about that on google sites..

[Google code discussion on this issue](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=189762)

There also is an [issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-146955) opened for IntelliJ for that.

So the solution is to stop developing on external screen.

EDIT: After update to 10.11.5 everything works just fine.

Comment: I get this issue constantly throughout the day and it's so freaking annoying. I came to the same conclusion as you with the links you've posted. If anyone else comes across this issue PLEASE leave a comment in the google discussion posted. Hopefully with enough complaints we can increase the priority in getting it fixed.

Comment: Today the problem isn't solved. Its really annoying if you do a lot of things, AS crashes and everything is gooooooone.... really nice feeling in that moment